# Get server response message from error

Tags: alamofire

My server (CakePHP) is responding like so:

```
$this->response->statusCode('400');
$this->response->type('json');
$this->response->body(json_encode(array('message' => 'Bookmark already exists')));
```

The Postman output looks like what you would expect:

{"message":"Bookmark already exists"}

The problem is that I cannot find a way to access this message from the failure handler (Alamofire 3.1.3 + SwiftyJSON 2.3.2)

```
Alamofire.request(.POST...
.validate()
.responseJSON { response in

switch response.result {

case .Success(_):                           
// All good

case .Failure(let error):
// Status code 400                 
print(response.request)  // original URL request
print(response.response) // URL response
print(response.data)     // server data
print(response.result)
```

I cannot find a way to cast response.data to JSON as a I simply get nil and the result returns just FAILURE.

Is there a way to access this server message from the failure handler ?

Answer (score 21):

The data is not parsed in the .Failure case per the [Alamofire 3.0 migration guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#result-type).  However, server data is still available in response.data and can be parsed.

Below should work to parse this manually:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://example.com/create", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
  .validate()
  .responseJSON { response in
     switch response.result {
     case .Success:
         print("Validation Successful")
     case .Failure(_):
          var errorMessage = "General error message"

          if let data = response.data {
            let responseJSON = JSON(data: data)

            if let message: String = responseJSON["message"].stringValue {
              if !message.isEmpty {
                errorMessage = message
              }
            }
          }

          print(errorMessage) //Contains General error message or specific.
     }
  }
}
```

This uses [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which provides the JSON struct to convert NSData.  Parsing NSData to JSON can done without SwiftyJSON, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840736/converting-json-to-nsdata-and-nsdata-to-json-in-swift).

Another cleaner option might be to write a [Custom Response Serializer](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#creating-a-custom-response-serializer).

Answer (score 8):

A method with the router and no SwiftyJSON:

```
Alamofire.request(APIRouter.Register(params: params)).validate().responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {

        case .Success(let json):
            let message = json["clientMessage"] as? String
            completion(.Success(message ?? "Success"))

        case .Failure(let error):
            var errorString: String?
            if let data = response.data {
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String] {
                    errorString = json["error"]
                }
            }
            completion(.Error(errorString ?? error.localizedDescription))
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to use [String: Any]. In my case, [String: String] does not work even if the message is a string.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the following lines to read the response body from a Alamofire request.

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, serveraddress, headers: headers, encoding: .JSON)
        .response{ request, response, data, error in
            let responseData = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(responseData)


    }
```

With this body I can get my custom server response errormessage.

best regards

Answer (score 1):

For Alamofire 4.0 and above :

Try this
response.response?.statusCode

url : "YOUR-URL"

parameters: "YOUR PARAMETER DICTIONARY"

headers: "YOUR HEADER DICTIONARY"

I am using SwiftyJSON for JSON Parsing

> A sample request is here :

```
func createPostRequestWith(path: String?,
                          parameters: [String : Any]? = nil,
                          success : @escaping (Any?) -> (),
                          failure : @escaping (NSError) -> ()) {

    if !(Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager()?.isReachable)! {
        let error = NSError(domain: "", code: -1003, userInfo: nil)
        failure(error)
    } else {
        guard let url = path else { return }
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: createCurrentHeader()).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            //Remove loader here either after parsing or on error
            case .success(let data):
                success(data)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                if let responseData = response.data {
                    var parsedResponseData = JSON.init(data: responseData)
                    let customError = NSError(domain: parsedResponseData["message"].stringValue, code: response.response?.statusCode ?? 555, userInfo: nil)
                    failure(customError as NSError)
                } else {
                    failure(error as NSError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```