# How can I convert a JSON as Data Type in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, websocket, swifty-json

I want to send data to my websocket server in swift but the websocket server write function only accepts strings or the data type. Since I did not find any JSON.stringify option for swift I used swiftyJson to create my own type of JSON, but now I need to convert it to data in order to be able to send it to the server.

```swift
var json: JSON =  ["name": "Jack", "age": 25]
socket?.send(data: json //<-- This needs to be Data)
```

I tried wrapping the JSON in Data(json) but this did not work either. Any ideas? I have swiftyJson installed if there is a solution for this.

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434702/14359662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is a literal

```
let json =  #"{"name": "Jack", "age": 25}"#
let data = Data(json.utf8)
```

With `SwiftyJSON` it's pretty simple, too, but less efficient.

```
let json: JSON =  ["name": "Jack", "age": 25]
let data = try! json.rawData()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = Data(json.utf8)
```

By the way, I would not suggest using external libraries for such simple tasks as you become dependent on third-party's works, on which you have no control over.
Stick with the foundation model instead.